# 1 or 0 Per Group

Tags: sql

Re-edited to make it clearer:

I would like my results  to appear as they do in 'Column b' based on 'Column a' groupings? so a 1 or 0 per group based on column a. Column b does not exist currently, I am trying to code this in.  I was trying to use row_number or rank but this not appear to work for me.  So how do I write my SQL so I can get my SQL results to mirror Column b? Any help is appreciated

Thank - you

| column a | column b |
| --- | --- |
| aaa | 1 |
| aaa | 0 |
| ddd | 1 |
| ddd | 0 |
| ddd | 0 |
| yyy | 1 |
| yyy | 0 |
| yyy | 0 |

Comment: Please format your output within backticks. I can hardly interpret your output

Comment: What are you trying to do? The logic is not clear enough .

Comment: Hi, apologies i have added more comments and an example if thats clearer?

Comment: You seem to want to add some logic to assign the first occurrence of a number in Column B to receive a value of 1, and all subsequent ones to receive the number 0. Is that correct? How do you determine the first occurrence, exactly? I.e. What makes the B1 value of `9999` different from the B2 value?

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. I want to assign a value of '1' per group so the first number per group will have a number '1'. If you look at b5 this has been assigned '1' as this is the start of a new group if that makes sense.? I was thinking if there was a way to use 'Rank' or 'Dense' for this? I don't think they would work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to wrap your row_number() in a case, something like this:

```
select
    column_a
    case row_number() over (partition by column_a)
        when 1 then 1
        else 0
    end as column_b
from 
    table
/
```